# Increment by 1, then 10, then 100?

Tags: javascript, increment

So Im trying to write my program to where every time the function is activated, the value of 'money' in local storage goes up by 1. When I tested it out, It does go up by 1. But the next time, it went up by 10, then 100. Why? I couldnt find anyone with the same issue. Heres the code:

```
<script>
  function changeText() {
    localStorage.setItem("money", localStorage.getItem("money") + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("map", true);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Because you're doing string concatenation rather than integer addition : `"1" + 1 = "11"`. I think you will want to use `parseInt(localStorage.getItem("money"))` to cast your stored value to a number, but careful about non-initialized values (`parseInt(localStorage.getItem("i don't exist")) == NaN`)

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.getItem("money")` will return a string, since it stores only string. When adding data to storage, it is implicitly converted to a string.

You can convert the string to number and then do addition and store the value

```
function changeText() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('money') === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('money', 1)
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("money", +localStorage.getItem("money") + 1)
  }

}
```

Comment: Ill give it a try

Comment: <script>
function changeText() {
localStorage.setItem("money", (+(localStorage.getItem("money")+1))
localStorage.setItem("map", true);
}
</script>

Comment: It doesnt work.

Comment: first check if there exist a key called `money` in `localStorage`

Comment: There is. It says "missing ) after arguement list line 3.

Comment: Also `(+(localStorage.getItem("money")+1)) ` seems to wrong, You need to convert the value from `localStorage`

Comment: @William check the update answer

Answer (score 0):

Try doing -

```
<script>
  function changeText() {
    var money = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("money"));
    localStorage.setItem("money", money + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("map", true);
  }
</script>
```

**parseInt** converts `string` to `number` so if you pass `parseInt("1")` it will spit out `1` which will be of type number. Then you can add `1` to the number.

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked!!! Omg thanks!

Comment: @William You are welcome. You can upvote & accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are alomost there! Like others metioned here, localstorage works with strings and to convert a string to number just use the folowing in your code to return the value as number:

```
Number(your_string_number)
```

This should work for you:

```
<script>
  function changeText() {
    localStorage.setItem("money", Number(localStorage.getItem("money")) + 1);
    localStorage.setItem("map", true);
  }
</script>
```